# CSS "counter-increment" not incrementing

Tags: html, css

Following [this tutorial](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201105/styling_ordered_list_numbers/), I am trying to style my list item counters in an `<ol>`.  However, my counters are not incrementing.

```css
.prog-ol ol {
  counter-reset:li; 
  margin-left:0; 
  padding-left:0;
} 
.prog-ol li {
  position:relative; /* Create a positioning context */
  margin:0 0 6px 2em; /* Give each list item a left margin to make room for the numbers */
  padding:4px 8px; /* Add some spacing around the content */
  list-style:none; /* Disable the normal item numbering */
}
.prog-ol li:before {
  content:counter(li); /* Use the counter as content */
  counter-increment:li; /* Increment the counter by 1 */
  /* Position and style the number */
  position:absolute;
  top:-2px;
  left:-2em;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:2em;
  /* Some space between the number and the content in browsers that support generated content but not positioning it (Camino 2 is one example) */
  margin-right:8px;
  padding:4px;
  border-top:2px solid #666;
  color:#fff;
  background:#666;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
 }
```

```html
 <ol class="prog-ol">
          <li>Foo</li>
          <li>Bar</li>
          <li>baz</li>
        </ol>
```

It seems like these two lines should pretty much take care of it:

```
content:counter(li); /* Use the counter as content */
counter-increment:li; /* Increment the counter by 1 */
```

Why aren't my counters incrementing?

Comment: Your `counter-reset` is not functioning because your selector is incorrect. `.prog-ol ol` should simply be `.prog-ol`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining your counter on `.prog-ol ol` which are the `<ol>` descendants of the element that is a member of the `prog-ol` class.

Remove the `ol` from the selector.

```css
.prog-ol {
  counter-reset:li; 
  margin-left:0; 
  padding-left:0;
} 
.prog-ol li {
  position:relative; /* Create a positioning context */
  margin:0 0 6px 2em; /* Give each list item a left margin to make room for the numbers */
  padding:4px 8px; /* Add some spacing around the content */
  list-style:none; /* Disable the normal item numbering */
}
.prog-ol li:before {
  content:counter(li); /* Use the counter as content */
  counter-increment:li; /* Increment the counter by 1 */
  /* Position and style the number */
  position:absolute;
  top:-2px;
  left:-2em;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:2em;
  /* Some space between the number and the content in browsers that support generated content but not positioning it (Camino 2 is one example) */
  margin-right:8px;
  padding:4px;
  border-top:2px solid #666;
  color:#fff;
  background:#666;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
 }
```

```html
<ol class="prog-ol">
          <li>Foo</li>
          <li>Bar</li>
          <li>baz</li>
        </ol>
```

(For that matter, you should probably remove the `ol` from the class name too. Tying class names to specific elements doesn't make a lot of sense. You can combine them with type selectors if desired).